# What type of attack is the below SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection

Today in the apache access log I saw something like this

```
https://xxxxx/xxxx/xx/something.html' or (1,2)=(select*from(select name_const(CHAR(103,119,111,107,69,82,84,99,118),1),name_const(CHAR(103,119,111,107,69,82,84,99,118),1))a) -- 'x'='x.html
```

It's an SQL injection attack but I am not able to figure out what the attacker trying to do.

And also the ASCII representation of the characters corresponds to "gwokERTcv" what does this mean?

Comment: Missing some important context. What exactly is that string? For example, is it contained in the URL that the hacker posted to your web server? Is it a string that he typed into the UserName textbox on the login page?

Comment: Which string are you referring to?

Comment: The attack. The string that you put in the gray box.

Comment: something.html is the the html file name and "gwokERTcv" is the char array 103,119,111,107,69,82,84,99,118 present. I will rephrase the question

Comment: that is the apache access log. I am just showing only the url which was captured

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty basic scan attack that can determine a couple of things on your system without much effort.

1. Is your system running MySQL
2. Will your system parse the SQL statement and return a value.

If your server responds appropriately to the command, the attacker knows that they can manipulate your database and potential exploit your system. Uh oh.

The good news is this is just a scan. Take it, see if you can make the command work on your own and learn how they want to attack from there.

More information on this can be seen here:

https://firegenanalytics.com/2017/12/splunk-review-121017/

-- Edit --

I just wanted to point out that they weren't trying to get anything from your database. They just attempted to create a temp table with some columns and values for their temp table to perform a command assessment. The values don't really mean anything.